# Как правильно хранить адрес картинок в БД?

Tags: php, mysql

В БД записан путь к картинкам. Я вывожу их через функцию с разных страниц, находящихся и в корневом каталоге и из разноуровневых папок.

*Как правильно записать адрес этих картинок в БД? Относительный или абсолютный?*

С относительным проблем нет, но только с определенных страниц. Каждый раз определять, откуда пришел запрос и менять имя картинки как-то несерьёзно. Прописываю абсолютный адрес типа `http://site.ru/forum/arhiv/1.jpg`, но после этого файлы не отображаются.

Comment: я не знаю, правильно ли это но я сохраняю "/forum/arhiv/1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

> http://site.ru/forum/arhiv/1.jpg

Если все лежат в одной папке и носят имена по айдишникам, то хранить вообще никаких путей не надо.

Comment: `http://site.ru` в базе можно не хранить

Comment: @Alex, а стоит ли хранить "/forum/arhiv/" ?

Comment: зависит от структуры сайта

Answer (score 0):

Используйте как вариант: `/forum/arhiv/1.jpg` или `1.jpg` в зависимости от структуры хранения данных. Абсолютные пути `http://site.ru/forum/arhiv/1.jpg` использовать не рекомендуется, т.к. например, при переходе на протокол HTTPS нужно будет править всю базу.

> С относительным проблем нет, но только с определенных страниц. Каждый раз определять, откуда пришел запрос и менять имя картинки как-то несерьёзно.

Что значит менять имя картинки? Отделите пути хранения изображений от путей вывода самих страниц. Например, страница может быть `http://site.ru/forum/arhiv/1`, а для хранения картинок используйте папку `http://site.ru/media/`.